# Permission denied - /dev/ttyS6 (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: ruby, windows, ubuntu, arduino, windows-subsystem-for-linux

the thing is that I'm trying to conect to the serial port 9600 with a ruby script that "I made" to send data so the Arduino can read it.

I want to send data to a serial port (9600), and I have to connect to the port to do it. I'm trying to connect it to `/dev/ttyS6`.

this is my ruby code:

```
#simplest ruby program to read from arduino serial,
#using the SerialPort gem
#(http://rubygems.org/gems/serialport)

require "serialport"

#params for serial port
port_str = "/dev/ttyS6"  #may be different for you
baud_rate = 9600
data_bits = 8
stop_bits = 1
parity = SerialPort::NONE

sp = SerialPort.new(port_str, baud_rate, data_bits, stop_bits, parity)
#just read forever
while true
  i = gets.chomp!.to_i
  puts sp.putc(i)
end
#puts i.class #String

sp.close                       #see note 1
```

I have my ruby program running on ubuntu bash for windows. This message shows up in the console:

```
serialport-1.3.1/lib/serialport.rb:25:in `create': Permission denied - /dev/ttyS6 (Errno::EACCES)
```

I already tried these solutions:

- `chown -R myUserName ./*`
- `sudo chown -R user_name file_name`
- `chmod a+w <folder>`

How can I allow the conection?

Comment: How did you decide `/dev/ttyS6` is the serial port?

Comment: "In WSL, the lxcore driver maps COM ports to Linux devices by the COM port number so /dev/ttyS<N> is tied to COM<N>.  More specifically, the mapping is on the minor number, so minor number 65 (/dev/ttyS1) is COM1, 66 (/dev/ttyS2) is COM2, and so forth. " says https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2017/04/14/serial-support-on-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/ so `/dev/ttyS6` would be COM6.

Comment: Why my question got -2 votes, not angry, just want to get the feedback so then I can ask better questions

Comment: Added a couple of updoots :)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I found the solution, I used this command:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyS6
```